# Cannot remove nameservers in GoDaddy when moving away from their hosting to external hosting

Tags: web-hosting, dns, godaddy

I will try to describe as best I can:

I have a GoDaddy hosting that came with a free domain name. I am now aware how bad GoDaddy is and have purchased hosting elsewhere, I need to change the DNS on the domain located at GoDaddy as the hosting I have do not allow for domain transfers.

I enter into the DNS records for my domain name and find the name servers section:
[image]

I have added the new ones as shown, however when I try to delete the old ones (top 2) it says they are read-only? Are GoDaddy providing a restrictive service here? Do I need to 'unlock' them? There is no option to do so in the menu.

If this cannot be resolved, how would I go about un-registering my domain name with GoDaddy and then buying it again through my new provider? is this possible. Any other options for me?

Comment: Maybe because this is a "free" domain as part of a hosting bundle? How long ago was this registered? Are you still within a cancellation period?

Comment: As well, I would suggest that you call them and see what it would take to change your plan. @w3d is on the right path. You probably bought a bundle with restrictions due to the price. I always suggest that people do not go cheap. Domain name registration and hosting is cheap enough, shaving a buck or two costs more in the end. You will likely find GoDaddy quite accommodating to your wishes. I have been dealing with GoDaddy since the beginning and found that they are a good company and their support is very good, but you will need to talk to them.

Comment: No, the nameservers are not restricted or tied to any product or service. Based on your screenshot, it appears you went one level too deep in their UI. Go to `My Account`, expand `Domains`, click `Launch` next to the domain you want to modify, then under the _Settings_ tab look for `Nameservers` and the _Manage_ link that appears under them. Click on that and then select the _Custom_ radio button and the _Enter custom nameservers_ link. Entering custom nameservers will replace the default informational nameservers.

Answer (score 5):

It's taken me a while to work this one out in the past. Dan is right in his comment above. To change the nameservers you can't do this from within the DNS Manager, you have to do it from within the Domain Manager. In case anyone else finds this question and is using their Premium DNS service as I have done for domain names not registered with GoDaddy (GoDaddy refer to these as off-site domains), the same still applies also.

1. After logging into *My Account*, click *Launch* next to Domains.

[image: GoDaddy MyAccount Domains feature]

2. Click on the drop-down arrow to the right of the domain name you wish to update.

[image: GoDaddy Domain Manager]

3. Select *Set Nameservers* from the drop-down context menu.
4. You'll then see a popup dialog from where you can select *Custom* nameservers and then specify them and click *Save*.

[image]

There are no restrictions forcing you to use GoDaddy's DNS services, unless you wish to use the vanity nameservers feature which then requires the domain registration and DNS to be with the same company in order to work for technical reasons (*glue records*).

Comment: Good screenshots, and point about the vanity nameservers - they do need to correspond to a domain inside the same GoDaddy account (some GoDaddy users have several accounts).